# Usage of apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe

When we refer something about both of our parents it would be something like

`This is my parents' home town.`

When we say something about opinions, which is right?

`This is the peoples' opinion`

OR

`This is people's opinion`

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possessive form of words which have ending in s has an apostrophe after s, such as '' parents' ", '' doctors' " etc.

However, people is already a plural noun *unless* its plural form '[peoples](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/people)' means:

> Plural peoples: a body of persons that are united by a common culture,
>   tradition, or sense of kinship, that typically have common language,
>   institutions, and beliefs, and that often constitute a politically
>   organized group.

[Merriam-Webster]

Therefore the correct way to denote opinion of people would be " people's opinion".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but we have `Teachers' Day` - how about this?

Comment: That's because the plural of teacher is teachers. Therefore since the day is celebrated for all the teachers, it is teachers' day. Unlike the word teachers, the word peoples doesn't exist.

Comment: I disagree  "peoples" is not a correct word. It has just a different meaning.

Comment: Thanks Rathony! Didn't know that. Google tells me it is verb.

Comment: I mean the following. Plural [peoples](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/people):  a body of persons that are united by a common culture, tradition, or sense of kinship, that typically have common language, institutions, and beliefs, and that often constitute a politically organized group

Comment: I just edited your answer. Please take a look if it is OK with you.

Comment: Google is not the best source for part-of-speech information.  It will help you find the most common use of a word, but that is almost never the only correct use.